# actions link causing unexpected error in post feed to fanpage (facebook php sdk)

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, hyperlink, action

I have a basic facebook application that allows users to post to a fanpage. Starting a few days ago users began getting the following error:

`[error] => Array
                                        (
                                            [message] => An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
                                            [type] => OAuthException
                                            [code] => 2
                                        )`

After some testing I found that I could resolve this error by removing the "actions" parameter from the post.

`$msg_body['actions'] =  array(
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'DineLogiK',
                                    'link' => 'http://www.dinelogik.com'
                                )
                            );`

Interestingly the post will actually go through successfully with the link displayed even though it throws an error.

[image]

Any ideas why this would be causing an error?

`$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body);`

Here is the facebook bug report https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/644446512269268/

Answer (score 0):

Same issues here, since a couple of days ago.

According Facebook Platform Status https://developers.facebook.com/status/

> 20 hours ago Platform API errors and increased latency
>
> 21 hours ago API Issues
>
> 21 hours ago Platform-wide issues

I've just confirmed that action links cause the issue.

It's a Facebook bug, I've just reported it: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/575996609160973/